# How to solve 'CMakeFiles/pcl_recognition.dir/src/cg/hough_3d.cpp.o: file not recognized: File truncated'?

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to build perception_pcl_electric_unstable package.

When I rosmake, I get:

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building stack ['perception_pcl_electric_unstable']
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['perception_pcl_electric_unstable']        
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/ira/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120710-030715
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['perception_pcl_electric_unstable'] to:
  ['flann', 'cminpack', 'pcl_ros', 'pcl']
  [ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages perception_pcl_electric_unstable.  This may take a few seconds.
  [ rosmake ] rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: libvtk-qt          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common           
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                   
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
   No Makefile in package rosbuild
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
   No Makefile in package roslang
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole           
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean               
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                     
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs     
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam               
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits     
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster             
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp               
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit                 
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> cminpack [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                   
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                         
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cminpack [PASS] [ 0.05 seconds ]                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps   
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                   
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                 
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< flann [PASS] [ 0.03 seconds ]                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]                                         
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< eigen ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen                     
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                     
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                 
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
   No Makefile in package roslaunch
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest                 
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> test_roslaunch [ make ]                                
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode                 
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_rosgraph [ make ]                                 
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters 
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< test_roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package test_roslaunch   
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools         
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rosgraph     
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> timestamp_tools [ make ]                               
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< timestamp_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package timestamp_tools 
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_nodelet [ make ]                                  
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package test_nodelet       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag                   
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> test_ros [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package test_ros               
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> test_crosspackage [ make ]                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< test_crosspackage ROS_NOBUILD in package test_crosspackage
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]                               
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> test_rosnode [ make ]                                  
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
   No Makefile in package rosmsg
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration
   No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rosnode       
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostopic [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> test_rosbag [ make ]                                   
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostopic ROS_NOBUILD in package rostopic               
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< test_rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rosbag         
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                               
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> test_topic_tools [ make ]                              
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs 
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice           
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs         
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package test_topic_tools
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf                   
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosboost_cfg [ make ]                                  
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosboost_cfg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosboost_cfg
   No Makefile in package rosboost_cfg
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                           
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
  [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesl: 100.1 sec ] [ tf: 10... [ 2 Active 56/102 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_operations.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<signed char>::stream(Stream&, const std::string&, int8_t)’:
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_operations.h:56: warning: use of old-style cast
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> test_rospack [ make ]                                  
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_operations.h: In static member function ‘static void ros::message_operations::Printer<unsigned char>::stream(Stream&, const std::string&, uint8_t)’:
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_operations.h:66: warning: use of old-style cast
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rospack       
    In file included from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/pcl_base.h:55,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/common/common.h:41,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/common/distances.h:40,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/impl/point_types.hpp:1231,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/point_types.h:289,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/recognition/include/pcl/recognition/ransac_based/model_library.h:42,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/recognition/src/ransac_based/model_library.cpp:40:
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h: In member function ‘uint32_t sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<ContainerAllocator>::get_fields_size() const’:
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h:80: warning: use of old-style cast
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h: In member function ‘void sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<ContainerAllocator>::set_fields_size(uint32_t)’:
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h:81: warning: use of old-style cast
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h: In member function ‘uint32_t sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<ContainerAllocator>::get_data_size() const’:
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h:84: warning: use of old-style cast
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h: In member function ‘void sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<ContainerAllocator>::set_data_size(uint32_t)’:
    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h:85: warning: use of old-style cast
    In file included from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/pcl_base.h:57,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/common/common.h:41,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/common/distances.h:40,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/impl/point_types.hpp:1231,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/common/include/pcl/point_types.h:289,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/recognition/include/pcl/recognition/ransac_based/model_library.h:42,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/recognition/src/ransac_based/model_library.cpp:40:
    /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/msg_gen/cpp/include/pcl/PointIndices.h: In member function ‘uint32_t pcl::PointIndices_<ContainerAllocator>::get_indices_size() const’:
    /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/msg_gen/cpp/include/pcl/PointIndices.h:44: warning: use of old-style cast
    /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/msg_gen/cpp/include/pcl/PointIndices.h: In member function ‘void pcl::PointIndices_<ContainerAllocator>::set_indices_size(uint32_t)’:
    /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/msg_gen/cpp/include/pcl/PointIndices.h:45: warning: use of old-style cast
    Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_recognition.so
    CMakeFiles/pcl_recognition.dir/src/cg/hough_3d.cpp.o: file not recognized: File truncated
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[3]: *** [lib/libpcl_recognition.so.1.6.0] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[2]: *** [recognition/CMakeFiles/pcl_recognition.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package pcl written to:
  [ rosmake ]    /home/ira/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120710-030715/pcl/build_output.log
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl [FAIL] [ 100.17 seconds ]                          
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                                
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs   
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pcl. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_srvs               
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
  [ rosmake ] Built 61 packages with 1 failures.                                  
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
  [ rosmake ] /home/ira/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120710-030715               
  [ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: libvtk-qt Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install flann cminpack pcl_ros pcl`
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38340/how-to-solve-%27cmakefiles/pcl_recognition.dir/src/cg/hough_3d.cpp.o:-file-not-recognized:-file-truncated%27-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means the file is corrupted.  It was probably cutoff while being written or something inappropriately wrote to it.

The easiest solution is to run make clean or rosmake --pre-clean on it.  You could also manually just remove the file itself.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0